# Autocad Developer: how to get Object Color in RGB mode by using C#

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

[image]

Hi All, I would like to get the Object Color in Properties in RGB Mode. I have try the code like `string cecolor = acDocComObj.GetVariable("CECOLOR");` but this does not return the in TrueColor. Anyone got idea on how to do it?

Comment: What does it give you now?

Comment: string format, like RGB:128,12,113 or 213(Index Number), or Pantone. Based on what user have select in Autocad.

Comment: @G.C.Looi You should include that information in your question, not just in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply I gave on Autodesk discussion group.

```
        AcadAcCmColor color = new AcadAcCmColor();
        int index = 0;
        if (colorName.ToUpper() == "BYBLOCK")
        {
            color.ColorIndex = AcColor.acByBlock;
        }
        else if (colorName.ToUpper() == "BYLAYER")
        {
            color.ColorIndex = AcColor.acByLayer;
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(colorName, out index))
        {
            color.ColorIndex = (AcColor)index;
        }
        else if (colorName.ToUpper().StartsWith("RGB:"))
        {
            string[] rgb = colorName.Substring(4).Split(',');
            color.SetRGB(int.Parse(rgb[0]), int.Parse(rgb[1]), int.Parse(rgb[2]));
        }
        else
        {
            string[] bookColor = colorName.Split('$');
            color.SetColorBookColor(bookColor[0], bookColor[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For any Entity in AutoCAD (e.g. line, circle, block, etc), you can use the .Color property (for .NET in-process API):

```
Entity ent = // get the entity here;
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Colors.Color c = ent.Color;
int[] rgb = new int[] { c.Red, c.Green, c.Blue };
```

As you mentioned out-of-process COM/ActiveX, you can try something similar:

```
AcadEntity ent = // get the entity here;
int[] rgb = new int[] { ent.TrueColor.Red, ent.TrueColor.Green, ent.TrueColor.Blue };
```

Comment: Thanks, however I afraid this is not the answer that could solve my problem because this code is for in-process but not for interop.

Comment: I have edited my answer, basically the same approach for COM/ActiveX